# Full calendar using sql values

Tags: javascript, c#, sql, fullcalendar

Want to get values from DB2 into the calendar so thought about using this approach but can't seem to get any values to show up so not sure what I may be missing:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "testCalendar.aspx/GetEvents",
        data: "{}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json"
    }).done(function (data) {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
            events: data.d
        });
    });
});
```

Here is my code behind:

```
 [WebMethod]
public static string GetEvents()
{
    var events = new List<Event>();
    var query = "SELECT CAST(EDATE as char(20) ccsid 37) as EDATE, CAST(SCDCOD as char(5) ccsid 37) as SCDCOD FROM SCHEDULE WHERE USRNAM = 'TJSTRATH'";

    using (var con = new OleDbConnection("Provider=IBMDA400;Data Source=ip;Default Collection=collection;User ID=id;Password=pass"))
    {
        using (var cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, con))
        {
            con.Open();
            using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        events.Add(new Event()
                        {
                            start = reader["EDATE"].ToString(),
                            title = reader["SCDCOD"].ToString()
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
            con.Close();
        }
    }

    var theSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    return theSerializer.Serialize(events);
}


public class Event
{
public string title;
public string start;
}
```

It for some reason won't put the values on the calendar... no errors though so not sure what I might be missing...

Comment: I guess you probably have a console error due to the fact that `scheduleArray` is a DOM element, not an array. Did you check that? Anyway why go through the level of indirection of creating a listbox? Either inject your events data directly into the Javascript or use one of the event feed designs as mentioned in the documentation (2nd and 3rd links down on this page: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-data). The listbox part seems to be entirely unnecessary.

Comment: I admitted to not being a javascript expert so that was just an idea.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: No problem but if you're going to be doing some JavaScript programming, now would be an excellent time to learn how to debug JavaScript using your browser's developer tools. Just like debugging any language, it'll save you a world of pain and confusion. The Console is generally the first place to start. Anyway all the main browser vendors have documentation and tutorials showing you how to use their tools (although they're all quite similar anyhow). IMHO Chrome has the best tools.

Comment: Yeah I've done a little Firefox has great developer tools. I looked to Javascript because I figured it was the best way to get a good functioning calendar.

Comment: It's definitely a good approach, and fullCalendar is a pretty good tool for most purposes in this area. Enjoy and good luck. Feel free to post on SO with any more issues once you've updated your design and code a bit. P.S. yes the Firefox tools are also excellent.

Comment: @ADyson i edited my question with a different approach.. check it if you can see what I may be missing.

Comment: can you show me the final JSON which is produced, please? The most likely thing is that the date output format is unparseable, but I can't be certain.

Comment: P.S. the ideal setup is the other way round, where you initialise the calendar, and then define the ajax call as a function within the `events` option, as per https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function . If you then enable the server to filter events by date, it's a more flexible solution because fullCalendar will only fetch events for the dates actually being displayed. If you end up with a long history of events in your database, this can drastically improve performance. If the user changes the date range on the calendar, it'll automatically request the relevant events at that time.

Comment: P.P.S in your webmethod I'm fairly sure if you specify the method as `public static List<Event> GetEvents()` and then just `return events;` it will do the JSON serialisation for you automatically. Certainly that's the case with this kind of function in MVC and Web API, I can't remember for WebMethods if you have to add an extra attribute to the method to set the serialisation format, but you can look it up.

Comment: Cool Jumping in a meeting here shortly but will mess with it more after lunch.  I thought maybe it was a date parse issue but it's the same format that works if I just put in 2018-05-17.  I'll mess with it appreciate your time !